# TV series or film where some have a technology allergy or aversity

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a UK television series episode or a film about a group of people wandering around (Britain). The group seem to suffer collectively from a technology phobia, for example they reacted badly to electicity cables and pylons and sought to avoid them. Also when entering a barn full of farm machinery they were shocked and closed the door. I believe it may have been a children's film or series as I was a child at the time of watching it in the mid to late 1970s.
I know it is not a lot to go on, but the imagery was so powerful that it stayed in my memory all this time and I would love to exhume the rest of the story.

Comment: If it was '80s rather than '70s, I'd guess at [The Tripods](http://www.gnelson.demon.co.uk/Tripods.html). Could it be that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like 1975 series, *The Changes*. Britain goes back to the stone age as all technology is abandoned. It was a children's sci-fi series on BBC. [Full details on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Changes_%28TV_series%29).

> The Changes posits a Britain where a sudden enveloping noise emanating from all machinery and technology causes the population to destroy them. The resulting upheaval displaces many people and reverts society to a pre-industrial age where there is a deep suspicion of anyone who may be harbouring machinery. Even the words for technology are taboo. The remnants of modern technology that escape destruction (such as electricity pylons) produce a physical and sometimes violent repulsion among those left in Britain.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in the comment, it's [The Tripods](http://www.gnelson.demon.co.uk/Tripods.html), though that was  '80s rather than '70s.

Comment: See Mark Hobleys answer - it was actually the Changes